# Join в SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Делаю join 2уx таблиц (зависимость (TABLE_1 : TABLE_2)  =>>  (1:M) ):

```
all_rows = db.session.query(
    TABLE_1
    ).filter(
            TABLE_1.field1 == value1,
            TABLE_2.field2 == value2
    ).join(
           TABLE_2
    ).filter(
             TABLE_2.field3 == value3
    ).all()
```

Потом хочу распечатать результат:

```
for rows in all_rows :
    print('*', rows )
```

Выдает почему-то только 1 строку и то только данные TABLE_1

Что я не так сделал?

Comment: А что делает `filter` с параметром через запятую? И как вы фильтруете `TABLE_2.field2== value2`, когда вы ещё не запросили `TABLE_2` вообще?

Comment: Делал сначала по примерам из интернета, потом решил знания MySQL и на ее логике состряпать запрос - итог в ответе, который работает, не знаю на сколько это верное решение, может правильнее по другому делать...

Comment: @CrazyElf, а алиас можно присунуть в мой ответ?

Comment: Я не настолько силён в `SQL` и коннекторах к нему )  Что увидел непонятного - написал. Дальше не помогу уже.

Comment: @АлексейБелкин если вы примерно представляете, какой запрос должен получиться, то можно посмотреть полученный SQL запрос просто через `print(str(all_rows))` и сравнить с тем, что вы хотели получить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-общем, решил логику MySQl подключить и разобрался. Не знаю на сколько это верный вариант, но работает:

```
all_rows = db.session.query(
                    TABLE_1.field1,
                    TABLE_1.field2,
                    TABLE_2.field3
                ).join(
                    TABLE_2, TABLE_1.id == TABLE_2.table1_id
                ).filter(
                    TABLE_1.field1== obj_el.value1,
                    TABLE_1.field2== obj_el.value2,
                    TABLE_2.field3 == obj_el.value3
                ).all()
```

Ну и печать самой выборки:

```
for row in all_rows :
    print('*', row.field1, row.field2, row.field3)
```