# Алиасы в SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

В прошлом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1427771/join-%D0%B2-sqlalchemy) реализовал запрос к БД.

```
all_rows = db.session.query(
                    TABLE_1.field1,
                    TABLE_1.field2,
                    TABLE_2.field3
                ).join(
                    TABLE_2, TABLE_1.id == TABLE_2.table1_id
                ).filter(
                    TABLE_1.field1== obj_el.value1,
                    TABLE_1.field2== obj_el.value2,
                    TABLE_2.field3 == obj_el.value3
                ).all()
```

Теперь возник вопрос, а как сюда добавить алиас? Например такого вида:

```
all_rows = db.session.query(
                    ......
                    TABLE_2.field4 * 10 as 'nameAlias'
                ).join(....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Может кому поможет:

```
all_rows = db.session.query(
                    ......
                    (TABLE_2.field4 * 10).label("nameAlias")
                ).join(....
```